# Style all <li> items in <ul> with Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a navbar that has 5 li elements inside ul element. I want to style all the li items with Tailwind CSS. Do I have to add class names to all 5 elements or is there a way I can point all li elements in ul's class.
I want this functionality with tailwind.css

```css
.nav-links li {
  margin-right: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul class="inline-flex mr-14 mt-10 uppercase text-base 
                    font-roboto font-semibold text-black cursor-pointer">
    <li>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="">Products</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/solutions">Solutions</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/contact">Contact us</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add class `space-x-6` in `ul` to add margin between `li`

Comment: This worked. But I needed space-x-16 for ~52px's.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the `<ul>` tag which will style all the `<li>` tags

Check list style type for tailwind [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can add class `listItem` in this way :

```css
.listItem {
   color:blue;
   font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul class="inline-flex mr-14 mt-10 uppercase text-base 
                    font-roboto font-semibold text-black cursor-pointer">
    <li class="listItem">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <router-link to="">Products</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <router-link to="/solutions">Solutions</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
      <router-link to="/contact">Contact us</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```